# WPF - ObservableCollection PropertyChanged event?

Tags: wpf, binding, observablecollection, propertychanged

I have an object which has a property of type `ObservableCollection<bool>`. It is bound to a list of checkboxes on a form  using TwoWay bindings. I would like to add a PropertyChanged notification to this so that if certain values are selected, some other ones get automatically deselected. Is there a way to do this?

The ObservableCollection.PropertyChanged event doesn't get triggered when a value in the collection gets changed and I'm using the MVVM design pattern.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would need to use your own class that implements the INotifyPropertyChanged interface.  You won't be able to use bool, but you can have a single property in your class that is that bool that you want.

Comment: I was hoping to avoid something like that... oh well thank you

Comment: The problem is that bool does not implement INotifyPropertyChanged.